# tf.split outputs tensors with a useless dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a recurrent neural network, the inputs are from mnist database, so they are 28x28 pixels images.

Here is my network model:

```
def _pre_activation(self, input_values, layer):
   return tf.add(tf.matmul(input_values, layer['weights']), layer['biases'])

def network_model(self, x):
    layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.rnn_size, self.nb_of_outputs])),
             'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.nb_of_outputs]))}

    x = tf.transpose(x, [1,0,2])
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, self.chunk_size])
    x = tf.split(x, self.nb_of_chunks, 0)

    lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(self.rnn_size)
    lstm_outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x_splitted, dtype=tf.float32)

    output = self._pre_activation(lstm_outputs, layer)

    return output
```

I get the following error:

> Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with
>   input shapes: [28,1,128], [128,10].

My problem is, from a tensor of shape `(28, 28)`, `tf.split` outputs a list of 28 arrays of shape `(1,28)`, but I want 28 arrays of shape `(28, )`.

I tried to iterate it to a new list and reshaping each array one by one, but the problem is no session is running at this moment, and no value exist in those tensors.

I didn't found any useful help on the internet, probably because that I don't know how to formulate my problem.